Do we need to renew DMARC and DKIM (TXT Record) in DNS if we change DNS Provider?
I'm shifting from DigitalOcean DNS to AWS's Route53,
I imported all the records from DO to route53. But it didn't imported properly.
So I entered manually all the details.
But after setting them up. I don't see images in my domain mails. And Nothing has been changed in backend or frontend.
Moreover can't receive or send email from that mail.

Note: Domain from Google Workspace

Initially checked the Frontend code. From where the images and html is being loaded.
But it was working beforehand of changing DNS.
Also I researched about googleusercontent which seems to cache images.
But applied all proposed solution:
Gmail's new image caching is breaking image links in newsletter
and
Email thumbnail URL changed to googleusercontent.com in gmail
with no luck.
Probably the reason of leading me to think it's DNS issue.
